# I want to create a chatLog ,but I don't know how to do it

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

Now I have a textview ,and I receive content message , I will do
NSString *speakText=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@\n%@\n%@",fromWho,content,_cheatView.text];
to show it .
But now I want to create a array to save all message ,
In a array like sample

```
> [0]  (first message 3pair key/value)
   >[0]
   >[1]
   >[2]
>[1] (second message 3pair key/value)
>[2]
>[x]
>[y]
```

I tried use

```
- (void)webSocket:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket didReceiveMessage:   (id)message;
{
NSString *toMessageJson = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:message];
    [toMessageJson dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *toMessageData =[toMessageJson dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *messageDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:toMessageData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
    NSMutableArray *logDic =[NSMutableArray alloc];

   [messageDic enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL * stop) {  
            if ([key isEqualToString:@"content"]) {     
                [logDic addObject:messageDic];
        }
    }];
```

But the logArray always only have 1 Object .

Comment: Can you show where and how you populate message and logArray. Giving only how you add message to logArray seems to be incomplete as it doesn't fully show what can cause the issue of having only 1 object in the array.

Comment: is (id)message always a dictionary? I assume message will always be a single message? and everytime you receive a new message this method will be called, am I correct?

Comment: @Joshua (id)message is JSON ,It's a single message ! When receive server's message it will be called!

Comment: can check if my solution works to what you need?

Comment: @Joshua I want a solution can let me get a mutableArray , It have every content message

Comment: like I said check my answer. its already declared as a mutableArray.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116963/discussion-between-joshua-and-just-lai).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that logDic is confusing. At first I thought logDic is a dictionary, proper naming should also take place.

Main issue I can see is that you are always creating logDic every time you receive a message.

So if you make logDic as a property or an iVar.

example:

`//WhatEverClassname
@interface WhatEverClassname(){
  NSMutableArray *logDic;
}
@end
@implementation WhatEverClassname
 -(id)init{
   if(!(self = [super init])){
      return nil;
   }
   logDic = [NSMutableArray new];
  return self;
}
@end`

then in your didReceived method you don't need to initialise it anymore.

This enumeration isn't actually needed.

`[message enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL * stop)  ]`

it should be like:

`if(message[@"content"] != nil)
   [logDic addObject:message[@"content"]]; // no point in looping if you are only expecting a specific key.`

Comment: I have try this ,but the logDic get "null" ,

Comment: Have you initialised it properly? have you check using breakpoints? if you are actually adding it to logDic?

Comment: I check again ,than I found the issue was i forget to new..thank you